# Is there a way to create a matrix in Octave with every element equal the previous one +10

Tags: math, matrix, octave

I'm trying to create this matrix that has every element in the rows equal to the previous one + 10 and the columns + 1
Example:

```
 [ 1.  11.  21
   2.  12.  22
   3   13.  23
 ]
```

I just finished the course and this was in the practice that I had didn't have a clue how to do it.

Comment: Did you explore around this: https://octave.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The example matrix you've shown can be made using broadcasting operations with individual arrays containing the directional components of the result.  In the horizontal direction, the number increase by 10 (starting with zero 10s).  In the vertical direction, they increase by 1 (starting with one 1).

So, at its simplest, we can do:

```
[0, 10, 20] + [1;2;3]
ans =

    1   11   21
    2   12   22
    3   13   23
```

(Note the , separates column elements and ; separates row elements)

Now, for larger arrays you can also use the index notation to create those arrays:

```
[0:10:40] + [1:4]'
ans =

    1   11   21   31   41
    2   12   22   32   42
    3   13   23   33   43
    4   14   24   34   44
```

note the `'` transposes the row vector into a column vector.

Last, you can use a variable for an arbitrary size:

```
 n = 4, 10*[0:n] + [1:n]'
n = 4
ans =

    1   11   21   31   41
    2   12   22   32   42
    3   13   23   33   43
    4   14   24   34   44
```

Comment: `[…]` is a concatenation operator, you don’t need it. It is considered cleaner to use parentheses to change the order of operations: `(0:10:40) + (1:4).'`.

Comment: True, but in an attempt to maintain continuity between examples it was one less notation change to explain.